along the real line $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty}|f(x)|=1$ , prove that $f(z)$ is a rational function.

Let  $f(z)$ be meromorphic on the upper half plane $H$ and continuous on $\bar{H}$. Moreover, on the real line $|f(z)|=1$, and along the real line $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty}|f(x)|=1$ , prove that $f(z)$ is a rational function.

Shall we consider $g(\zeta)=f(-i+\frac{2}{\zeta-i})$, so that $g$ mapsto the unit disk to $\Bbb C$, and meromorphic; $g$ mapsto the unit sphere into the unit sphere. How can we deduce from this?

If $|f(z)|=1$ on the real line, isn't it redundant to add the limit condition?

My sphere, do you mean circle?

$f(z)=e^{iz}$ verifies all the conditions but is not rational.

When you write $\bar{\mathbb H}$, do you mean its closure in the plane or in the Riemann sphere?

You actually need $|f(z)| \to 1, |z| \to \infty$ unrestricted in the upper plane
